# Java Spring: criar um arquivo e oferecer este para download via api

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Olá

Eu tenho alguns documentos salvos no banco de dados (com modelos equivalentes, não são arquivos .txt nem nada), gostaria de criar arquivos .txt e .md desdes dados do banco, buscando pelo modelo, extraindo o título e conteúdo para formar um arquivo e adicionando uma extensão, e depois oferecer esse arquivo para download.

Encontro muitos exemplos de download de arquivos, esse seria somente uma parte, a primeira seria gerar um arquivo customizado somente quando solicitado pelo cliente.

Onde eu poderia encontrar exemplos baseados nisso?

Obrigada.

Document.java

```
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, encontrei uma forma de fazer, não sei se é a mais correta, mas essa função está me retornando o link do arquivo gerado.

DocumentControler.java

```
//passo o título do arquivo que tenho salvado no banco de dados
@GetMapping("/download/title={title}")
public File download(@PathVariable("title") String title) {
    Document document = service.findByTitle(title);
    //busco o documento pelo título

    File file = new File(title + ".txt");
    //adiciono o título como nome do arquivo

    try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        String contents = document.getDescription();
        writer.write(contents);
        //adiciono o conteúdo do documento ao arquivo

        return file;
        //retorno a url onde ele foi gerado.

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Então é só acessar a url e baixar o arquivo.